# Use import statement in Babel plugin

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, package.json, esmodules

I'm currently writing a babel plugin.

I have a folder called `plugin` a `package.json` and the following file:

```js
// index.js
import template from "@babel/template";

module.exports = function(babel) {
  // some code
}
```

Then I have a folder called `test-plugin`. It also has a `package.json` and the following `babel.config.json`:

```json
{
  "plugins": ["../plugin"]
}
```

When I run `./node_modules/.bin/babel test.js`, I get the following error:

```
import template from "@babel/template";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

So, I add `"type": "module"` to `plugin/package.json` and try again. This time I get this error:

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import 'path/to/plugin' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from path/to/test-plugin/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.18.10/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/import.cjs
Did you mean to import path/to/plugin/index.js?
```

So in `babel.conifg.json`, I try the following:

```json
{
  "plugins": ["../plugin/index.js"]
}
```

Now I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: [BABEL]: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/path/to/plugin/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension. (While processing: /path/to/plugin/index.js)
```

Now I still don't know how to resolve the original error? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try using
`const template = require("@babel/template");` in index.js

Comment: @AnandBhushan If I do that, it does compile, but when I try using the imported function `template`, it gives me a runtime error: TypeError: path/to/plugin-test/test.js: template is not a function